# Latex Package Get Document Geometry For Use In Package

Tags: packages, geometry

Is there a way to retrieve the geometry of a .tex file from the .sty file?

I would like to automatically be able to pull in the following:

- Page Width
- Page Height
- Top Margin
- Bottom Margin
- Right Margin
- Left Margin

The goal is to use it in the following setup:

## .tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,landscape,top=.5in,bottom=.5in,right=.25in,left=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}

\end{document|
```

## .sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[yyyy/mm/dd]
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{calculator}
\newlength{\TBMar}
\newlength{\RLMar}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}
{
%example function
\LENGTHADD{\TopMargin}{\BottomMargin}{\TBMar}
\LENGTHADD{\RightMargin}{\LeftMargin}{\RLMar}

\the\TBMar

\the\RLMar
}

\endinput
```

The purpose of knowing these is related to tikz images, diagrams.

Comment: I think I almost understand what you're asking: are you trying to figure out the geometry loaded by a particular package, but without loading any other definitions from that package?  And use that geometry within `mypackage.sty`?  It appears that you are trying to figure out the total margins in your mypackage.  Why?

Comment: `\paperheight`, `\paperwidth`, `1in+\topmargin`,  `\paperheight-\topmargin-\textheight-1in`, `1in+\@oddsidemargin`, `\paperwidth-\textwidth-\@oddsidemargin-1in`

Comment: @Teepeemm it is related to tikz. I just didn't think it was necessary to explain thr context.

Comment: David Carlisle has shown relevant calculations, but that's not necessarily the margins set by a particular `somepackage.sty`.  That's also not necessarily the margins that you will have at some point in your document.  It might be a lot easier to explain your context and why you want to know the margins.

Comment: @cdickstein You are not telling us what you needs these length for in tikz, but maybe have a look at the `tikzpagenodes` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the following code.

```
\newif\ifGP@geometrypreviouslyloaded
\GP@geometrypreviouslyloadedfalse

\@ifpackageloaded{geometry}
  {\GP@geometrypreviouslyloadedtrue}
  {\GP@geometrypreviouslyloadedfalse%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{\GPOpt@geometry}{geometry}%
    \RequirePackage{geometry}%
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\Foo{}
{
\paperwidth  % page width
\paperheight % page height
\Gm@tmargin  % top margin
\Gm@bmargin  % bottom margin
\Gm@rmargin  % right margin
\Gm@lmargin  % left margin
}
```

Comment: This still feels like you're taking the hard way to figure out what you want.  But because you've not told us what you want, we can't really help you.